# How garbage collector release AsyncTask allocated memory

Tags: android, memory, android-asynctask

In the MainActivity, every x seconds I create a new AsyncTask and I call execute with `new RTask(this).execute(param);` to send data to a server asyncronously. I think that create a new task so often can cause memory leaks. So when garbage collector release the memory and how can I set the task reference to null to allow to collect it?
I've tried to use `this.cancel(true);` within `onPostExecute()` but I've read that, due to a bug of the Android framework, onpost is never called. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure onPostExecute is never called, i seem to use it and have not been disappointed with it, quite often.. but yes getting back to the prime area of concern, GC, try setting it to null and manually remove all the references made to this variable, try n isolate it.. and also yes this.cancel(true) additionally should be ok

Comment: @stack_ved   
Thanks for your answer, I feel relieved, so when I instantiate a new task, the previous one (that has finished his task) will be automatically collected from the GC because his reference will be set to null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there shouldn't be any issue with `AsyncTask` recycling unless You hold any reference to it from `param` or generate memory leaks inside `doInBackground()`.

So, You might think, that if You're creating many long-running AsyncTasks then it would lead to some memory issues. Actually it's not true (at least on latest Android versions). `AsyncTask` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.2_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java/) shows that

- It uses singleton bounded executor:

  ```
  private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 5;
  private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 128;
  private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

  public static final Executor THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR
      = new ThreadPoolExecutor(CORE_POOL_SIZE, MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE, KEEP_ALIVE,
              TimeUnit.SECONDS, sPoolWorkQueue, sThreadFactory);
  ```

  That means that executor won't run more than 128 AsyncTasks the same time (128 is not very big per my understanding).
- It uses bounded query for the Executor:

  ```
  private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
          new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10);
  ```

So, based on the above points, number of created and running the same time `AsyncTasks` are limited and not so big. So, if Your code inside `AsyncTask` doesn't create any memory leaks, then per my understanding there's no issue. Same time Android won't let You spam itself with `AsyncTasks`. Checkout [ThreadPoolExecutors description](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to get familiar with the way it manages a memory (If You worry about too many created threads the same time).

Especially in Your case, I don't think that it's a good idea to execute another request to the server while previous one is not finished yet (in case of similar requests), also there's no point to execute many frequent small requests - Your app will draw battery too fast in this case.

Regarding `cancel()` call, based on [Android documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> Cancelling a task
>
> A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking cancel(boolean).
>   Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to
>   return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object), instead
>   of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked after
>   doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is cancelled
>   as quickly as possible, you should always check the return value of
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if possible
>   (inside a loop for instance.)

So, I'm not sure that You've meant by "I've tried to use this.cancel(true); within onPostExecute()" while `cancel()` has nothing to do if called from `onPostExecute()`. It can be called out from `AsyncTask` or from `doInBackground()` and it's a good practice to call [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29) if You have a loop in `AsyncTask` in order to stop its execution once `cancel()` called.

Comment: If I pass the MainActivity to the AsyncTask constructor in order to change an activity global variable value, there will be problems?

Comment: If You'll keep Your AsyncTask running indefinitely, then I would suspect problem in there. However, if You're just doing network requests, then after timeout / response it get finished and AsyncTask would end => no leak.

Answer (score 1):

> How garbage collector release AsyncTask allocated memory

Like it releases memory for any other class. There is nothing special about an AsyncTask. Once the task is done it will be garbage collected as long as no other class refers to it. Setting the task reference to null will help.